# How to insert an svg image in angular dashboard?

Tags: angular, svg

I'm bulding a webapp with Angular 6 (I'm a beginner with this tool). I have some problems in inserting an svg image in a card of the dashboard's page. I inserted the image in the folder "assets" and I installed "InlineSVGModule", but I didn't undestand how to use it for my purpose.
I create a component "map" with this ".html" file:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6" style=" overflow-x: hidden" >
   <div class="card" style="margin-left: 20px"> 
    <div class="card-body"style="align-content: center">
     <img [inlineSVG]= "'./assets/img/Immagine.svg'">
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
```

but it doesn't work.
Hope that you can help me.

Comment: Why you not use directly src to include the svg image? Check browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img

Comment: The path should be `assets/img/Immagine.svg`. You could just write `<img src="assets/img/Immagine.svg" />` without using the InlineSVGModule.

Answer (score 0):

You can include svg image directly:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6" style=" overflow-x: hidden" >
   <div class="card" style="margin-left: 20px"> 
     <div class="card-body"style="align-content: center">
        <img src= "./assets/img/Immagine.svg">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img).

[Here an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgoqzo)